# convert float pointing number to integer in c programing

Tags: c

I have a sine equation which return a float value like:

`0.0034,.000006,6.1684332059801899768737349875082e-4`.

I want to convert the corresponding float value to integer variables and pass it to a register to generate the particular sine wave graph.

Please help me out.

Comment: assign it to `int` variable. like `int   var_b = (int)var_a;` look https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/round.html

Comment: typecast each float value to int.

Comment: Why can't you generate sine wave with float values, if you convert it to `int` you will lose precision.

Comment: @Jayesh : Range of sine function is `[-1, 1]`. Typecasting sine values to `int` will make it a square wave or a staircase graph.

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild yes, right..but quickly commented after only seeing question title.

Answer (score 4):

If you're getting values like `0.0034`, you can't simply cast that to an `int` since it will come out as zero. In fact, the majority of floating point values between zero and one will come out as zero.

You need to first scale up the value, *then* cast it to an integer.

For example, to turn the output of a `sine` function into a value between -100 and 100, you could use something like:

```
int val = (int)(fpVal * 100);
```

That will turn the range `(-1,1)` (but mostly `0`) into something more usable, `(-100,100)` (with slightly better distribution across the range).

You may also want to *round* the value rather than truncate it, to ensure the values generated more accurate represent the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the float value into 3 unsigned integers, one for the values left of the decimal point and two for the values on the right of the decimal point.
For example, we get the float number "359.042042" and save it as variable flt.

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int int1, int2, int0;

    float flt = 359.042042;

    int1 = floor(flt);
    int2 = (flt - int1) * pow(10.0, 8.0);
    int0 = 8 - log10(int2);

    printf("%d.", int1);
    while (int0 != 0)
    {
        printf("0");
        int0--;
    }
    printf("%d", int2);

    return 0;
}
```

int1 are the digits on the left side of the decimal points, int2 are the digits on the right and int0 are the "0" before int2.
This would print "359.042042". Good luck.